How can I export excel without any column format?
This is my code to export data from table to excel..
function exportToExcel() {
var table = document.getElementById('data-table');
var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(table, {sheet: "Sheet1"});
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'exported_data.xlsx');
}    

My problem is that I have a date like this..
And the exported data looks like this..
What I expect is that the output is same as it is like in the data table.

Try dateNF and cellDates setting in options. Format List
